# What is the recommended Mailman3 web cron job configuration under Debian?

Tags: debian, mailman

The [Mailman3 web installation instructions](https://docs.mailman3.org/en/latest/config-web.html#scheduled-tasks-required) ask for the configuration of various cron jobs.  This is not specified in the [Debian Mailman3 installation instructions](https://salsa.debian.org/mailman-team/mailman-suite/-/blob/master/debian/README.Debian), which might suggest that the Debian `mailman3-full` package sets up what is required.  Yet no cron jobs are listed in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`.

In addition, trying to run the specified jobs from the command line (e.g. `sudo -u list mailman  /usr/bin/mailman-web runjobs hourly`) results in the error: `ValueError: Language code already registered: ar`.

Comment: Wht about `/etc/cron.d/mailman3`?  https://sources.debian.org/src/mailman3/3.3.7-3/debian/mailman3.cron.d/  (not an answer, because I'm not a Debian user and I might be pointing in the wrong direction)

Comment: Ah, all is there; great! Would you like to answer it?

Comment: Will do. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mailman3` package on Debian installs a set of cron schedules in

```
/etc/cron.d/mailman3
```

This should (with the current version of the software) look like the following:

```
# /etc/cron.d/mailman3: crontab entries for the mailman3 package

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# At 8AM, send out notifices of pending requests to list moderators
0  8 * * *  list    if [ -x /usr/bin/mailman ]; then /usr/bin/mailman notify; fi

# At 12AM, send mail digests for lists that do periodic as well as threshold delivery
0 12 * * *  list    if [ -x /usr/bin/mailman ]; then /usr/bin/mailman digests --periodic; fi

# Every 15 minutes, gate messages from usenet to those lists which have the gateway configured
*/15 * * * *   list    if [ -x /usr/bin/mailman ]; then /usr/bin/mailman gatenews; fi
```

(See https://sources.debian.org/src/mailman3/3.3.7-3/debian/mailman3.cron.d/)

Comment: Thank you!  Also, kudos for showing how to determine the answer: use the package's source code.